# What is the meaning of the word "savvy" in this context?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I'm not a native speaker of English. I wish to know what the word *savvy* means in this context:

> network-savvy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Savvy* in this context refers to someone who has some practical knowledge of networks.  See for instance this [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/savvy).

I personally really like this word, and it has been my experience that computer techs use it a lot behind the scenes to describe whether or not a user can receive instruction.  For instance,

> Is he computer-savvy or am I going to have to go down there and turn on his computer myself?

Also used to query for depth of knowledge

> How network-savvy is she? Do you think she would know how to `ping` her server?

Comment: I found this word reading and old Java programming language features doc. So in that is written: Java is network-savvy but because it's not a person how can I interpret well?

Comment: @josh Probably in that context it means "Java has useful network-communication-related programming libraries"

Comment: @BradC, yes it seems the more likely meaning. Thanks.

Comment: @xdevel2000 Yes, BradC has the right idea. If you're not talking about a person, then "savvy" would still indicate that whatever it is (in this case Java) understands networks. The most sensible way to interpret that would be as @BradC suggested.

Answer (score 3):

'X-savvy' means well-versed in the intricacies of X, or knows a lot about X.

It can be used stand-alone, as in "That person is very savvy about political conspiracies"

It comes from the French 'savoir' - to know how.

It can also be used as a verb 'Do you savvy?' of 'Savvy?' meaning 'Do you understand?' (it sounds very 'Pirates of the Caribbean')

Comment: Ahh, yes. Pirate-savvy use of [savvy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=savvy).  See for comparison Gangster use of [Capice](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=capice), although I think the response to "Capice?" should be "Capisco."

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=savvy) also cites the Spanish "sabe" as a possible origin.  I'm inclined to think the verb-form came first, as "Savez-vous?" degenerates to "Savvy?" in a very obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to denote familiarity and experience with a particular field.